# Checkbox selecting all checks when one checkbox is selected

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls, userform

I have a userform that I am building that has a check box entry on a field "TOPrint", when one checkbox is selected it however selects all the other checkbox also. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? I have my code on the 'On Click' event

The code works exactly how I want it too, although, I do not want all the check boxes to automatically check when only one is selected. Any advice?

```
Private Sub ToPrint_Click()

        ' Selecting CheckBox on ToPrint
          If ToPrint = True Then
          User52 = fOSUserName()
          Requested_ON = Date
          End If

        'Unselecting CheckBox on ToPrint
         If ToPrint = False Then
         ToPrint = False
         User52 = Null
         Requested_ON = Null
         End If
End Sub
```

This code defines my function fOSUserName()

```
  Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
       "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

         Function fOSUserName() As String
       ' Returns the network login name
      Dim lngLen As Long, lngX As Long
      Dim strUserName As String
      strUserName = String$(254, 0)
      lngLen = 255
      lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
      If (lngX > 0) Then
      fOSUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1)
    Else
      fOSUserName = vbNullString
    End If
 End Function
```

Comment: You say the checkbox is bound to field TOPrint? If it is not bound to a field, then that is the nature of UNBOUND control because there is only one control - every instance will display the same value unless it has a calculation with dynamic term.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the question to include exact steps how to set up such "userform" - just the minimum needed to replicate the behavior you're seeing. Note that, if this behavior is independent of any VBA code it probably should be better asked in an end-user venue, such as Super User.

Comment: If User52 and Requested_ON are also UNBOUND, same issue as with checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the checkbox is UNBOUND. In which case the behavior you describe is the nature of UNBOUND control because there is only one control - every instance will display the same value unless ControlSource is a calculation with dynamic term.

I presume you use a checkbox because the form is in Datasheet view. Don't use an UNBOUND checkbox, use an UNBOUND textbox formatted to look like a hyperlink. Textbox properties:
ControlSource `="Print"`
DisplayAsHyperlink `Always`

If the form is in Single or Continuous view, use a command button.

Then you don't have to be concerned about checking/unchecking a checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the response but a hyperlink will not work due to it not actually being printed right away. Whenever a user selects 'ToPrint' checkbox and then clicks on this button it sends it to a tbl, which is then linked to a userform for another user to see what has been requested.

Comment: Also yes the checkbox is unbound and i however did add an IIF statement behind the checkbox's control source and I am still receiving an error. Which is: "Control cannot be edited; it's bound to the expression '=IIF(]chkboxToPrint] = true, [txtUser52=fOSUserName()), "")'

Comment: Correct, cannot set value of a control that has an expression. Can't get what you want with UNBOUND checkbox. Period. Expression in control cannot set value of another control. The hyperlink is not really a hyperlink, just looks like hyperlink as a visual clue to users this is a clickable element. Code in event would set User52 and Requested_ON. Are these bound controls?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am new to VBA so really cant explain things well. Yes the three controls, checkbox, user52, and requested on are unbounded. I guess I am asking how would I make them bounded to the form that way I am able to update these fields based on the selection of the checkbox

Comment: Must be fields in table. Table must be part of form's RecordSource. Set ControlSource to field. Is this a multi-user database? Multiple simultaneous users could conflict with each other setting field values. Are you wanting to allow users to select multiple records for print to a report? Selection must be based on data in records - filter criteria. UNBOUND controls will not accomplish that.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! With that being said how would you suggest I add a make field as a checkbox? (In design view)

Comment: You add fields to table. Make sure table/field are included in form RecordSource. This is basic Access functionality. I don't know your data structure and cannot advise specifics.

Comment: To answer your question above yes, this is for multiple users' to select what they wish to be printed.. I ended up doing a make tbl based on the SQL table with raw data, then I added the three field "ToPrint, Requested_ON, and User52" to the make tbl in datasheet view. Then I connected my main form to this make table. However on the checkbox "OnClick" whenever I put code behind it and try to check a box it is saying "Recordset is not updateable".. Going back and looking at the checkbox's record source it is connected to the same field in the make table... man I am completely lost

Comment: Disregard that message. I finally figured it out! Thanks you were extremely helpful and patient

Comment: If multiple users try to do this at same time, they will conflict and not get expected output. Database needs to be split with each user running their own copy of frontend and 'temp' table maintained in frontend so each user has their own. I set 'temp' tables as permanent but data is temporary.